# what does this error message on my chrome extension, from popup.html mean and how to fix it?

Tags: google-chrome, connection

So as you already read in the title my problem hast todo with popup.html

I have no idea what the problem is please help me!

this is the error code

Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Stacktrace
popup.html:0 (Anonyme Funktion)

popup.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #popup-container {
        width: 600px;
        height: 800px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>DissBott</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>ChatGPT Extension</h1>
    <p>input</p>
    <textarea id="input"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    <button id="clearButton">Clear</button>
    <br>
    <p>Response:</p>
    <p id="response"></p>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js is:

```
// Popup Script
//background.js


const submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
const clearButton = document.getElementById("clearButton");
const promptTextarea = document.getElementById("prompt");
const responseParagraph = document.getElementById("response");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // onClick's logic below:
  // Get the prompt from the textarea
  const prompt = input;
  // Send the message to the background script
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    message: "clicked_browser_action",
    prompt: prompt
  }, function(response) {
    // Display the response
    responseParagraph.innerText = response;
  });
});

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Clear the textarea
  promptTextarea.value = "";
  // Clear the response
  responseParagraph.innerText = "";
});
```

my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "DissBot",
  "description": "This is an extension that uses the ChatGPT model.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://api.openai.com/"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
     "script": ["bg.js"]
    }
}
```

I tried to make a chrome extension it didnt work.

Comment: You should post your manifest.json and javascript files.

Comment: A syntax error in manifest.json should have been output, so please check it.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
document.getElementById("send").onclick = () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage("send", (respose) => {
    console.log(respose);
  });
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(message);
  sendResponse("response");
  return true;
});
```